# Converting number base

Tags: haskell, base-conversion

Is there a platform function that will do the following?

```
convertBase :: (Num a, Num b) => Int -> Int -> [a] -> [b]
```

Convert a number from base 'a' to base 'b' where each list item is a digit in the number. 
for example:

```
convertBase 2 10 [1,1,0,1] = [1, 3]
```

*I hope that makes sense, let me know if i can clear anything up*

Comment: by platform function you mean part of the standard libraries?

Comment: Why distinguish the types `a` and `b`, aren't they just some `Integral`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using the [digits](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/digits/latest/doc/html/Data-Digits.html) package from Hackage:

```
import Data.Digits (digits, unDigits)

convertBase :: Integral a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
convertBase from to = digits to . unDigits from
```

You can add a `fromIntegral` in there if you need the input and output types to be different. Also, the `Integral` constraint makes more sense than `Num`, since you probably don't want to deal with complex or floating-point digits.

Comment: The resulting function accepts a list of integrals. If I create a `decToBin = convertBase 10 2`, what does it mean to use `decToBin [10,10]`?

Comment: Oh I found out that `decToBin [10, 10]` is the same as `decToBin [1010]`. It just concatenates all the numbers in the list.

Answer (score 8):

The closest thing in the haskell platform is from module [Numeric](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Numeric.html):

[`readInt :: Num a => a -> (Char -> Bool) -> (Char -> Int) -> ReadS a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Numeric.html#v:readInt)
[`showIntAtBase :: Integral a => a -> (Int -> Char) -> a -> ShowS`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Numeric.html#v:showIntAtBase)

```
fromBase :: Int -> String -> Int
fromBase base = fst . head . readInt base ((<base).digitToInt) digitToInt

toBase :: Int -> Int -> String
toBase base num = showIntAtBase base intToDigit num ""

fromBaseToBase :: Int -> Int -> String -> String
fromBaseToBase from to = toBase to . fromBase from
```

Comment: Which is easily extensible if you provide your own "intToDigit" function supporting bases > 16

Answer (score 2):

Couple of ideas:

- use showIntAtBase or Text.printf to convert to a string, and convert back to a different base
- write it yourself -- easier when one base is always a multiple of the other

Here is a link that might help you: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Non-decimal_radices/Convert#Haskell -- Non-decimal radices/Convert