# How to use 'Numeric.showIntAtBase'?

Tags: haskell

In [the `Numeric` module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Numeric.html), I find the following function `showIntAtBase`.
Could I use for convert a decimal number into a binary or octal number?

Does this function work like this?

```
showIntAtBase 6 1025554775 =  245433110435
showIntAtBase 2 5264564526752765267240006 = 10001011010110100001001110101100111000111110101011111100100100001010110010001000110
```

If it doesn't work this way, can you tell me any predefined ones to do this?

Comment: Here's [an existing good solution to the "convert a number's base" problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10028866/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what you are asking:

> Does this function work like this?

```
showIntAtBase 6 1025554775 =  245433110435
```

1. No.  The function defined in Numeric does not work by pattern matching all possible numbers and providing a literal result.
2. No. The code you typed is not type correct. You haven't even provided the correct number of arguments.

Notice the type for showIntAtBase:

```
> :t showIntAtBase
showIntAtBase
  :: (Show a, Integral a) => a -> (Int -> Char) -> a -> ShowS
```

Expanding for the `ShowS` type alias we get:

```
> :t showIntAtBase
showIntAtBase
  :: (Show a, Integral a) => a -> (Int -> Char) -> a -> String -> String
```

So you need to provide four arguments, not two numbers.  For example, you can use `Data.Char.intToDigit` to convert integers to characters and you can use the empty string for the suffix string:

```
> import Data.Char (intToDigit)
> import Numeric (showIntAtBase)
> showIntAtBase 6 intToDigit 1025554775 ""
"245433110435"
```

Comment: How I could convert `"245433110435"` to Integer?

Comment: Use `read` or `Data.Text.readMaybe` if you don't trust the input is valid.